# Is a java scanner's nextLine function guaranteed to delimit only on newline characters?

Tags: java, newline

I was looking at the documentation for this function, and they seemed to word it really vaguely.

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.
>   Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line to skip if no line separators are present.

By "any line separator", should I interpret this to mean things like NUL, EM, FS, ETX, etc, or just the first newline character it encounters?

I really wish the javadocs were a little more explicit.

Comment: NUL, EM, FS, ETX, etc are not line separators.

Answer (score 6):

[OpenJDK's source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/Scanner.java#494) shows that `nextLine()` uses this regex for line separators:

```
private static final String LINE_SEPARATOR_PATTERN =
                                       "\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]";
```

- `\r\n` is a Windows line ending.
- `\n` is a UNIX line ending.
- `\r` is a Macintosh (pre-OSX) line ending.
- `\u2028` is [LINE SEPARATOR](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm).
- `\u2029` is [PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2029/index.htm).
- `\u0085` is [NEXT LINE (NEL)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0085/index.htm).